# How change the background color of first cell in a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Is everything okay?

I have the following table in my java application. 
By the status he makes the line a certain color, as I will show in the code below.

What I want is that only the first column is colored, the others want to appear with the default color.

```
public class PriorityCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
            table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

    //if (Integer.valueOf(1).equals(table.getValueAt(row, 1)) && 0 == column)   && 9 < column)
    if (String.valueOf(1).equals(table.getValueAt(row, 0))) {
        setForeground(Color.BLUE);  // or background
    }
    if (String.valueOf(2).equals(table.getValueAt(row, 0))) {
        setForeground(Color.GREEN);  // or background
    }
    if (String.valueOf(3).equals(table.getValueAt(row, 0))) {
        setForeground(Color.YELLOW);  // or background
    }
    if (String.valueOf(4).equals(table.getValueAt(row, 0))) {
        setForeground(Color.RED);  // or background
    }
    return this;
} 
}
```

[image]

Realized my question?

Does anyone can help me please?

Thank you very much.

Comment: remove the other ifs?

Comment: That should it be: `if (0 == column) setBackground(Color.RED)`

Comment: Thanks all for reply. I tried this: if (String.valueOf(1).equals(table.getValueAt(row, 0))&& column == 0) {
            setForeground(Color.BLUE);  
        }           But the result is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Set custom renderer for target column:

   ```
   table.getColumnModel().getColumn(COLUMN_INDEX).setCellRenderer(new PriorityCellRenderer());
   ```
2. in `getTableCellRendererComponent()` validate column index `if(column == COLUMN_INDEX)`

Comment: code posted, described qeustion is job for prepareRenderer()

Comment: @mKorbel, you are right, that can be done in `prepareRenderer()` method of `JTable`